# How to use functions provide by DataFrameNaFunctions class in Spark, on a Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and I want to use one of the **replace()** function of 
**`org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions`** on that dataframe.

**Problem:** I don't get these methods in intelligence (suggestions) with dataframe's instance. I imported that class explicitly.

I am not able to find any stuff which can give me some demonstration of how to use these functions or how to cast dataframe to type of `DataFrameNaFunctions`.

I tried to cast it using `asInstanceof[]` method but it throws exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be a bit confusing but it's quite straightforward to be honest. Here is an small example :

```
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("na_test.csv")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> df.show()
// +-----+----+
// | name| age|
// +-----+----+
// |alice|  35|
// |  bob|null|
// |     |  24|
// +-----+----+

scala> df.na.fill(10.0,Seq("age"))
// res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

// scala> df.na.fill(10.0,Seq("age")).show
// +-----+---+
// | name|age|
// +-----+---+
// |alice| 35|
// |  bob| 10|
// |     | 24|
// +-----+---+

scala> df.na.replace("age", Map(35 -> 61,24 -> 12))).show()
// +-----+----+
// | name| age|
// +-----+----+
// |alice|  61|
// |  bob|null|
// |     |  12|
// +-----+----+
```

To access `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions` you can call `.na.`

Comment: ya.. You are actually right. I am so sorry for this kind of silly question. But I wasn't having an idea of that .na variable can get access on functions of DataFrameNaFunctions. Really, Thank you for approaching. @eliasah