# Spark Scala - Handling empty DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a specific requirement wherein, i need to check for empty DataFrame. If empty then populate a default value. Here is what i tried but not getting what i want.

```
def checkNotEmpty(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, col: String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
 {
 if (!df.rdd.isEmpty())  df
    else
  df.na.fill(0, Seq(col))
 }

val age = checkNotEmpty(w_feature_md.filter("age='22'").select("age_index"),"age_index")
```

The idea is to get the df if it is not empty. If it is empty then fill in a default value of ZERO. This doesn't seem to work. The following is what i am getting.

```
scala> age.show
+---------+
|age_index|
+---------+
+---------+
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2):

```
  def checkNotEmpty(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, col: String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
     {
     if (!df.rdd.isEmpty())  df
        else
      df.na.fill(0, Seq(col))
     }
```

In your method :

control goes to `if` part if the `df is not empty` .

And goes to `else` part when `df is empty` .

[df.na](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html) (`org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions`) : Functionality for working with missing data in DataFrames.
Since you are using `df.na on an empty dataframe` , there is nothing to replace hence result is always `empty`.

Check this [ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499941/how-to-use-functions-provide-by-dataframenafunctions-class-in-spark-on-a-datafr) for more on replacing null values in df.

Comment: Thanks @p2. Is there a way to fill in a default value of ) when it is empty

Comment: thanks again. It is still not working as i expected.
`
def checkNotEmpty(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, col: String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
{ 
 if (df.rdd.isEmpty()) 
 { 
    println("here"); 
    df.na.fill(0.0,Seq(col))
 } 
 else 
    df 
}
`
I tried the above as well. The value is not NULL but empty and hence i don't think **df.na.fill** works in this case..

Comment: check this ques : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376571/replace-null-value-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: you can try somthing like this: df.na.replace("age", Map(35 -> 61,24 -> 12))).show()

Comment: thanks once more.. This did not help either. I was not sure what are we doing, but did what you had suggested. Below are the things what i tried.

**
scala> age.na.replace("age",Map(35->61,24 ->12)).show()
+---------+
|age_index|
+---------+
+---------+

scala> age.na.replace("age_index",Map(35->61,24 ->12)).show()
+---------+
|age_index|
+---------+
+---------+

scala> age.na.replace("",Map(35->61,24 ->12)).show()
+---------+
|age_index|
+---------+
+---------+
**

Comment: i guess it should be : age.na.replace("age_index",Map(""->"EMPTY_VALUE")).show()

Comment: that is not working either. Thank you so much for all the help so far.